# I don't understand why "return" doesn't return a value

Tags: android, kotlin

I'm new to kotlin and I don't know English well so "Google Translate hello!".
I want to return the values that I received during the execution of the if condition. This function iterates through the columns in the excel table until it finds the one I need and returns its number

I tried to write `return@getTableValue`  to indicate where to return the value, but it didn't give anything, I don't understand, help

My code:

```
private fun getTableValue(xlWs: Sheet, groupe: String, dopgroupe: String): Int {

        var gr: String
        var cellNumb: Int
        var res: Int

        for (i in 0..20){
            gr = xlWs.getRow(0).getCell(i).toString()
            if (gr == groupe){
                cellNumb = i

                if (dopgroupe == "1") {
                    res = cellNumb
                }
                if (dopgroupe == "2") {
                    res = cellNumb + 2
                }
            }
        }

        return res // Error Variable 'res' must be initialized
    }
```

Comment: You should assign val in all path. If you are sure it will get a value, you can use lateinit var instead.

Answer (score 0):

You only set `res` inside if statements, so the compiler cannot be sure that you ever set a value to `res`. You can only use a variable’s value after it is guaranteed to have been set to something. In this case, the easiest solution is to give the variable an initial value at the declaration site, like this:

```
var res: Int = 0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I thought that he does not see changes in other operators, so I thought that if I give the initial value, he will only display it